# extra \ in json response before every / in java, android

Tags: java, android, url, escaping, jsonresult

My code to get image Urls

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
```

where server code is in php

But problem is there is extra \ before every /
e.g. in database image Url is, `http://www.dvimaytech.com/markphoto/upload/herwadeshirish123@Gmail.com/Pic.jpg`
but I get every time `http:\/\/www.dvimaytech.com\/markphoto\/upload\/herwadeshirish123@Gmail.com\/Pic.jpg`

Is this problem isn't solvable, then another solution(its last option for me) is to remove every .

But when I try that using `url = url.replace("\","");` 
it gives syntax error `String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a JSON parser library like gson to decode your JSON packets for you.
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

It will make your life much easier and avoid having to string.replace() specific characters.

Comment: or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), for example. Either way, it shouldn't be done with string replaces. Also, I would [validate](http://jsonlint.com/) the original JSON to see if it is actually JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to handle that

```
public static String extractFileName(String path) {

    if (path == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String newpath = path.replace('\\', '/');
    int start = newpath.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (start == -1) {
        start = 0;
    } else {    
        start = start + 1;
    }
    String pageName = newpath.substring(start, newpath.length());

    return pageName;
}
```